# How to change video brightness?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen-brightness

Whenever I watch any videos, either through the Gallery, Play Movies, or YouTube, my screen becomes substantially brighter. After searching online, I suspect there's a separate video brightness setting, but there's no apparent way of accessing it. It doesn't show up in system or any of the app settings. Does anyone know how to find and adjust this video brightness setting?

If it's of any concern, I have a Huawei Ascend P1 running almost-stock Ice Cream Sandwich, with auto-brightness enabled.

Comment: You may refer to [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/114284/96277) if the device is rooted.