# Playing a video in MX Player Pro turns the phone's brightness to extremes. What is the cause?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-9, mx-player

Used MX Player Pro for years on my S6, S8 but on my new Note 9 every time I try to play a video the brightness of the whole phone screen goes to extreme brightness that I have to turn the phone fully away to close the app.

What is the cause & fix? Note 9 is a year old phone so I thought any issues would be fixed by now.

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Why does video screen get brighter and how to prevent it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105130): MX Player has a setting to override screen brightness while playing a video.

Comment: @Andrew T. Saw that linked one before posting.Unrelated as my issue turns not just the video bright but the whole phone screen clock & all. In 2019 on my Samsung Note 9 none of it those solutions linked to apply.